# Set minimal pages count in pdf using flying saucer

Tags: pdf-generation, itext, flying-saucer

Is there any way to set minimal count of pages to pdf? So my current need looks like:

- I have an header on second page that should be shown
- First page has content that can overflow to second page
- It is not acceptable to have 3 pages

So I need 2 pages in both cases:

- First page fits to single page (so I should create second page manually)
- First page overflows (at create second page by its content)

Single workaround that I found - overflow by empty (`<br/>`s) content. But I wanna do it with css.

I've tried to use `@page:first` but it wouldn't work in common css manner (like `@page:first .break-page{...}`)

I've tried to use `@page:first {break-page-after:always}` - it wouldn't work...